# What could these numbers mean?

Tags: vectors

I have some 3D vector data with the following parameters: X, Y, Z, v.X, v.Y and v.Z. I know the first three are just cartesian coordinates, but I don't know what the last three are, I just know they define the direction of the vector. Here are some of the values:
[image: sample data]

What do they mean? How can I use them to rotate vectors defined, let's say, along the X axis, to get to the correct direction? Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Maybe this helps: I initially asked that the direction is defined using

$\cos(\phi)\cdot\cos(\theta), \sin(\phi)\cdot \cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)$, but that's obviously not the case because the norm of the direction vector is not 1. I tried normalizing it, but then when I plotted the vectors using the extracted theta and phi, they didn't look correct. There's also a chance I'm not rotating around the correct axes...

Comment: Could you post the whole table? Perhaps it's some calculated value of the other coordinates ...

Comment: I doubt it is, but I'll post it anyway (not all rows, but all columns).

Comment: The "p" and "v" suggest that the first three columns might contain the coordinates of a set of "positions", and the second three columns the components of a set of "velocities".  I can't see how it could be possible to arrive at any more definite conclusions than that from the information you've provided. Where did the table come from?

Comment: "I have some 3D vector data" did you try asking the person who provided it to you?

Comment: Like Ionza pointed out, the best guess is that the first three are positions and the last three are velocities. So you have vectors $u_i$ along with their respective velocities $v_i$, so you can simulate their position for example like so $u_i(t) = u_i(0) + t v_i$ (where $u_i(0)$ is the initial position of $u_i$). 
If you want to rotate the directions/velocities (and not the vectors themselves) you just need to manipulate the velocities $v_i$. If you want to rotate the velocity $v_j$ about the x-axis by $\theta$ then you just assign $v_j\longleftarrow R_x(\theta)$ (search rotation matrix)

Comment: Thank you all! Yes, @lonzaleggiera, you are right. Columns 4, 5, 6 are velocity vectors. I tested that assumption and the vectors plot nicely.